# Do you need to escape any characters when utilizing jQuery.css() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, escaping

I have a situation where dynamic CSS is being passed in via another attribute (so not by users) and I was wondering if any escaping needed to occur when using this method?

I thought that perhaps quotes needed to be escaped as setting the background style via css may end up with this:

```
<div style="background-image: url("my-image.png");">
```

Wouldn't those doubles quotes in that style declaration need to be escaped since they are already inside double quotes?

I tested it out though and it doesn't *seem* to cause an issue.

Is this needed or not?

Comment: You don't need those quotes around `my-image.png`, alternatively you could just use single quotes.

Comment: If you are "typing" in your HTML you would write `<div style="background-image: url(&quot;my-image.png&quot;);"></div>`. However, you do not have to html encode if you are manipulating style property va JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tested it out though and it doesn't seem to cause an issue.

It *will* cause the issue, if you are setting it like the way you have shown:

```
<div style="background-image: url("my-image.png");">
```

just because you specify your style in double quotes and the style is interpreted to be ending after `url(`. You can wrap it in the single quotes, then it wouldn't.

Setting this via jQuery won't cause any problems:

```
$("div").css({"background-image":'url("my-image.png");'})
```

because the first snippet is just how it would look to the user; javascript can't set the attribute so as it would mess the whole html; it would be auto-escaped anyway.

In short, if you told the javascript to work just with one attribute, it would do so and won't touch any other parts of element. If you didn't mess up with quotes, javascript won't do it :)

Comment: OK good to know. Yes, wouldn't *write* it like that myself, just wasn't sure if it was auto-escaped or not.